# How to check largest possible palindrome integer

Tags: python, palindrome

I am working on an assignment which requires me to use a function takes two arguments: an integer in string form, for example '1921', and an integer k, for example 2. The function returns the largest possible palindrome integer that one can find by changing at most k digits of the input number to any other digit 0-9.

For example, with at most two changes to 1921, the largest possible palindrome number is 1991 (with one change 2 -> 9). If we had three changes, we would get from 1921 to 9999, the highest possible integer value with four digits.

I believe the code I am using checks if the number is a palindrome, but doesn't give me the largest possible palindrome I can get.

Code used:

```
def Is_palindrome(str):
    x = 0 
    for i in range (len(str)/2):
        if (str[x]) == (word[len(str)-x-1]):
            x+=1
        if x == (len(str)/2):
            return True
    return False

def longest_palindrome(str):
    lst = str.split() 
    palindromes = [] #List that contains the palindromes
    long_len = 0 #Length of the longest palindrome
    longest = "" #The actual longest palindrome
    for i in lst: 
        if Is_palindrome(i): #If the str is a palindrome
            palindromes.append(i) #Add it to the palindrome list
    for i in palindromes: #Loop through the palindrome list
        if len(i) > long_len: #If the palindrome is longer than the 
longest one
            longest = i #Set it as the longest one
            longest_len = len(i) # Set the length of the longest one to 
the length of this one
    return longest
```

Please let me know if you have any suggestions!! Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi. I don't understand: In your text you say that your function has two arguments a string and k; however I can see only the string one. Is that normal?

Comment: Hi I am new to python and in my class I have been taught to only work with strings alone. I am not sure how to write a function that would work both the string and k. That's why I think my function is incomplete and doesn't work for my given problem.

Answer (score 1):

Please try the following code:

```
import sys

def maximumPalinUsingKChanges(str, k):
    palin = []

    a = 0
    b = len(str)

    while (a < b):
        palin.append(str[a])
        a = a + 1

    # Iinitialize l and r by leftmost and
    # rightmost ends
    l = 0
    r = len(str) - 1

    #  first try to make string palindrome
    while (l < r):
        # Replace left and right character by
        # maximum of both
        if (str[l] != str[r]):
            palin[l] = max(str[l], str[r])
            palin[r] = max(str[l], str[r])
            k = k - 1
        l = l + 1
        r = r - 1    

    # If k is negative then we can't make
    # string palindrome
    if (k < 0):
        print("Not possible")
        return "Not possible"

    l = 0
    r = len(str) - 1

    while (l <= r):
        # At mid character, if K>0 then change
        # it to 9
        if (l == r):
            if (k > 0):
                palin[l] = '9'

        # If character at lth (same as rth) is
        # less than 9
        if (palin[l] < '9'):
            #If none of them is changed in the
            #  previous loop then subtract 2 from K
            # and convert both to 9 
            if (k >= 2 and palin[l] == str[l] and palin[r] == str[r]):
                k -= 2
                palin[l] = '9'
                palin[r] = '9'

            #  If one of them is changed in the previous
            #  loop then subtract 1 from K (1 more is
            #  subtracted already) and make them 9  
            elif (k >= 1 and (palin[l] != str[l] or palin[r] != str[r])):
                k = k - 1
                palin[l] = '9'
                palin[r] = '9'

        l = l + 1
        r = r - 1

    print(''.join(palin))
    return ''.join(palin)
```

Make sure k is an integer & not string

Comment: Very well done, I was looking at this earlier and figured out would have to go about it by adressing the edges first, but I was stumped about addressing possibilities for certain combinations of changes and K, good work here my friend

Comment: @vash_the_stampede thank you. Happy to help. Glad it worked.

Comment: @vash_the_stampede it is okay man there will be many opportunities